# Scaling a tkinter project to fit 320x240 raspberry Pi screen

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, raspberry-pi, resolution

I am working on a tkinter GUI which utilises a canvas widget in order to have an image in the background, and widgets above.This GUI will run on a `320x240` raspberry pi screen.I am new to designing GUIs for these screens, having only developed for laptops in the past. Currently the GUI looks like this:

**Actual Outcome**
[image: too small]

As you can see, it is far too small. What I want is:

**Expected Outcome**

[image]

The reason I have made the geometry `320x240` is because I want to run this GUI on my Raspberry Pi Screen which is `320x240`. The pi however mirrors the output of the HDMI cable to the screen. The HDMI outputs `1280x480`. I just need it too look sharp on the raspberry pi screen, **it doesn't matter how stretched it looks on the HDMI output.**

**Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except:
    import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.geometry("1280x480")

#Define Canvas
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=320, height=240)
canvas.grid(row=1,column=1)


# translates an rgb tuple of int to a tkinter friendly color code
def _from_rgb(rgb):
    return "#%02x%02x%02x" % rgb

# Called when user presses View Log button
def viewLogRaise():
    #Hide Previous Windows
    canvas.itemconfigure(logButtonWindow, state="hidden")
    canvas.itemconfigure(titleLabelWindow, state="hidden")
    #Open Closed Windows
    canvas.itemconfigure(backButtonWindow, state="normal")
    canvas.itemconfigure(logTextWindow, state="normal")
    quote = """HAMLET: To be, or not to be--that is the question:
    Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer
    The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune
    Or to take arms against a sea of troubles
    And by opposing end them. To die, to sleep--
    No more--and by a sleep to say we end
    The heartache, and the thousand natural shocks
    That flesh is heir to. 'Tis a consummation
    Devoutly to be wished."""
    logText.insert(tk.END, quote)

def backToMenu():
    #Hide Previous Windows
    canvas.itemconfigure(backButtonWindow, state="hidden")
    canvas.itemconfigure(logTextWindow, state="hidden")
    #Open Closed Windows
    canvas.itemconfigure(logButtonWindow, state="normal")
    canvas.itemconfigure(titleLabelWindow, state="normal")

# Background
pathToGif = "redpoly2.jpg"
# red_background=Image.open("redBackground.gif")
backgroundImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=pathToGif)
canvas.background = backgroundImage
bg = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW, image=backgroundImage)
titleLabel = tk.Label(root,fg="white", text="TEXT",borderwidth=2,relief="solid", bg=_from_rgb((239, 36, 37)), font=("Courier", 44))
titleLabelWindow = canvas.create_window(160,90,window=titleLabel)
logButton = tk.Button(root,fg="white",text="View Log",command=viewLogRaise,borderwidth=2,relief="raised",bg=_from_rgb((239, 36, 37)), font=("Courier", 22))
logButtonWindow = canvas.create_window(160,180,window=logButton)
backButton = tk.Button(root,fg="white",text="Back",command=backToMenu,borderwidth=2,relief="raised",bg=_from_rgb((239, 36, 37)))
backButtonWindow = canvas.create_window(20,227,window=backButton)
canvas.itemconfigure(backButtonWindow, state="hidden")
logText=tk.Text(root,bg="white",height=12,width=35,borderwidth=2,relief="solid")
logTextWindow = canvas.create_window(160,110,window=logText)
canvas.itemconfigure(logTextWindow, state="hidden")
root.mainloop()
```

**What I tried**

I used `root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)`, thinking this would scale the contents of the root frame to match the screens resolution, however this line only makes the tkinter window full size.

I thought about resizing the whole GUI to run on `1280x480` however this would mean that their would be too many pixels for the pi screen to show.

**redpoly2 image**

[image]

Comment: You question isn't clear — am not sure what you want to know. I also can't run your code because you haven't provided the `redpoly2.jpg` image.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `create_window` for you widgets rather than using `pack` and/or `grid`? In general, `pack` and `grid` do a fantastic job of scaling your UI based on the window size. If you're explicitly placing windows at specific coordinates, you're completely responsible for handling resolution differences.

Comment: @BryanOakley I am using a canvas because I wanted to have a background image. I couldn't find a method of assigning an image to a frame as frame doesn't have a image attribute.

Comment: @martineau I have provided the image.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, I'm not familiar with the raspberry-pi and its "regular" output vs HDMI. Regardless, if you want the GUI to fit on 320x240, why are you setting `root.geometry("1280x480")`?

Comment: @martineau I was experimenting. If the GUI looked sharp on the desktop monitor, perhaps it would look sharp on the screen.

Comment: In that case — since you say you don't care what the HDMI output looks like — it seems like you could just set the size to 320x240 and position the widgets with x and y values relative to that. To give it some flexibility, you could use _proportional_ coordinate values and scale them according to the current root window size before use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a background image without using a `Canvas` widget and doing so will allow you to use tkinter's geometry managers to place your widgets. I don't really understand the relationship between the Raspberry Pi's 320x240 screen and the 1280x480 HDMI one.

The code below illustrates how to display a background image and some widgets on top of it. There's also a `Button` to toggle the window's size between the two you want.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except:
    import tkinter as tk


path_to_bkgr_img = "redpoly2.jpg"
WIN_SIZES = (320, 240), (1280, 480)


# Translates an rgb tuple of int to a tkinter friendly color code.
def _from_rgb(rgb):
    return "#%02x%02x%02x" % rgb

def change_size():
    """ Sets/changes window size to next one available in WIN_SIZES. """
    global cur_size
    cur_size = (cur_size + 1) % len(WIN_SIZES)
    config_window()

def config_window():
    """ Sets root window's title, size, and background image. """
    global background_label

    geometry = '{}x{}'.format(*WIN_SIZES[cur_size])
    root.geometry(geometry)
    root.title(geometry)

    # Resize background to fit window size.
    btn_img = background_image.resize(WIN_SIZES[cur_size], resample=Image.BICUBIC)
    btn_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(btn_img)  # Make tkinter compatible.

    if not background_label:  # Create Label if necessary.
        background_label = tk.Label(root)
    background_label.config(image=btn_img)
    background_label.image = btn_img  # Keep reference.
    background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)


root = tk.Tk()
background_image = Image.open(path_to_bkgr_img)
background_label = None
cur_size = 0
config_window()

titleLabel = tk.Label(root, fg="white", text="TEXT", borderwidth=2, relief="solid",
                      bg=_from_rgb((239, 36, 37)), font=("Courier", 44))
titleLabel.pack(padx=5, pady=5, expand=1)

logButton = tk.Button(root, fg="white", text="Change Size", command=change_size,
                      borderwidth=2, relief="raised", bg=_from_rgb((239, 36, 37)),
                      font=("Courier", 22))
logButton.pack(padx=5, pady=5, expand=1)

root.bind_all('<KeyPress-Escape>', lambda *event: quit())  # Press Esc key to quit app.
root.mainloop()
```

Here are screenshots showing the what's displayed for each size:

[image: screenshot of small window]

[image: screenshot of large window]

Answer (score 0):

The output of the RPi can be configured within the `config.txt` file on the /boot partition. By referencing [the config.txt video page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md) you can set the output of the HDMI to a specific mode. In your case this may require custom settings which are described [here within the raspberry pi forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=24679).

You specify the new mode in `config.txt` with the following config string:

`hdmi_cvt=<width> <height> <framerate> <aspect> <margins> <interlace> <rb>`

Where:

```
Value       Default     Description
width       (required)  width in pixels
height      (required)  height in pixels
framerate   (required)  framerate in Hz
aspect      3           aspect ratio 1=4:3, 2=14:9, 3=16:9, 4=5:4, 5=16:10, 6=15:9
margins     0           0=margins disabled, 1=margins enabled
interlace   0           0=progressive, 1=interlaced
rb          0           0=normal, 1=reduced blanking
```